# Why my application from store not visible for tablet samsung tab p3100?

Tags: android

my application from store visible for acer tablet that is android 3.2.1 but it not visible for samsung tab p3100 that is 4.1. What can i do?

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- This permission will allow us request the connection changes. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- This is required to start our service from BootCompletedIntentReceiver. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of `android:targetSdkVersion="11"`. It should be android:targetSdkVersion="16" for that.

---

Permission `android.permission.CAMERA` implies requirement of features `android.hardware.camera` **and** `android.hardware.camera.autofocus`. Samsung Galaxy Tab 2   (***p3100***) doesn't have autofocus. May be it is the reason.

[Permissions that Imply Feature Requirements.](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions-features)

SO you can try with adding below line into manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: but when I change android:targetSdkVersion from 11 to 16 is it will be visible for phones that work in android 2.1 because i set minimum sdk 7 for phones android 2.1

Comment: thats not a problem.. you set minsdkversion to 7 so that will be visible for 2.1 always